# REST service from Android : 400 exception

Tags: android, web-services, rest, basic-authentication

I am very new to Android development so excuse if my tries are not 100% correct.

In JavaScript, I have a function that connects to a WCF service, with basic authentication, to retrieve a base64-encoded string for a requested PDF document. The JavaScript, below, works:

```
function svcPost(param) {
    return jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'https://url-to-service.svc/' + param.method,
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: JSON.stringify(param.json),
        async: true,
        processData: true,
        crossDomain: true,
        beforeSend: function (request) {
            request.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + window.localStorage.getItem('credentials'));
        },
        success: function(result) {
            return result;
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
            return error;
        }
    });
};
```

This function would then be called in a promise to return the aforementioned base64 encoded string:

```
jQuery.when(
        svcPost({ method: 'GetBase64Pdf', json: { id: lookupId } })
    )
    .done(function (result) {
        deferred.resolve(result[0]);
    })
    .fail(function(error) {
        console.error(error);
    });
```

I am trying to replicate this in an Android application, and I'm having no luck. Every call to the service returns a 400 BAD REQUEST, stating that the call is expecting a 'type' with 'value', but found null.

I know this has something to do with '**dataType: 'json'**', but I cannot seem to get this working in Android.

The code I have so far:

```
byte[] bytes = "Username:Password1".getBytes("UTF-8");
String encoded = Base64.encodeToString(bytes, 0);
String itemid = Integer.toString(lookupId);

String param = "id=" + URLEncoder.encode(itemid, "UTF-8");
String url = "https://url-to-service.svc/GetBase64Pdf";

URL uri = new URL(url);
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)uri.openConnection();

try {
    connection.setRequestMethod("POST");                        
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", Integer.toString(param.getBytes().length));
connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + encoded);     

connection.setDoOutput(false);
connection.setUseCaches(false);
connection.setDoInput(true);

DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
wr.writeBytes(param);
wr.flush();
wr.close();

InputStream in = null;

int status = connection.getResponseCode();

if (status >= HttpStatus.SC_BAD_REQUEST) {
    in = connection.getErrorStream();
}
else {
    in = connection.getInputStream();
}

BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
String line;
StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
    response.append(line);
    response.append('\r');
}

rd.close();
```

I have tried adding '**Accept**' as a header entry for '**dataType: 'json'**' but this does not work.

If I add '**&type=json**' to the parameters string, it returns the error message as a json array.

Is there something a miss? I don't have access to the WCF service, it is a 3rd party call on  a client's environment, so I cannot check the services itself. The JavaScript works, but I cannot replicate the JavaScript implementation in Android.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I have been tearing at this for hours an no blog I've read has had any success :(.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set doOutput to true:

```
connection.setDoOutput(true);
```

You are setting it to false and so no output (request-body) is sent.